# Elastic Search SQL Server Synchronization

Tags: sql-server, elasticsearch, synchronization

I'm currently doing real time synchronization with elastic search (upon save in database, I save on elastic search).

The problem that I have is synchronization of all entitites through some tool (probably Logstash) - though I'm not sure about best practices. I would like to be able to synchronize specific entity (or all entities), which is not a problem since I have DB View for each entity but I'm not sure about performance of whole DB synchronization, and are there any limitations on logstash/other tools?

Basically the idea is to run full synchronization on initial project setup, and then just run synchronization if something goes wrong or model changes and needs elastic search update. I don't have too many records for now (<1M overall I'd say).

Any suggestion would be well appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JDBC plugin of logstash. You can even use the cron job style scheduler that is built in the plugin.

The documentation is here [JDBC input Plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html)

But you have to understand that Elasticsearch is a Search Engine. So real-time is not possible but near real time is.